My json input contains object and arrays, how can I convert it into dataset
My json input contains object and arrays, how can I convert it into dataset?
I referred existing stack overflow solutions but didn't find anything that works.
Need help with the solution, available deserialization methods are not working for deserializing json with objects and arrays
